# SSD sata 2.5 inch drive - how to identify fault

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, sata, samsung-ssd

I have a SATA 2.5 inch Samsung 1TB SSD drive (870QVO). I am have put the computer innards into a new case and I found that in the new case the computer would not start with the drive attached. Fans would jerk on the first time and then all is quiet. System can start to bios well with the SSD drive removed. Or replacing the power cable between the PSU and the drive - computer starts to BIOS, but the drive is invisible in BIOS.

Then I tried to see the drive with a SOGATEL SATA/IDE usb bridge with my laptop it does not come up at all. Other spare drives would work, I would be able to mount and read data, but this one does not appear at all.

**Question 1:** Does the problem description suggest some electrical fault within the drive (that might have happened while I was moving the drive, although there was nothing unusual)?

**Question 2:** Would there be a way to recover the SSD drive image, given the problem description? I can replace the drive, but it contained linux and windows OSes as well as some data. If I have to lose that, I have to, but if there are ways of reading off faulty SSD, that would be good to know.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried the drive on another computer?

Comment: Well, I tried the SATA usb bridge, but I can try in another computer too\

Comment: PC is failing POST - if it is the drive itself that is causing the POST failure, boot with a different drive and use an external case to attach the SSD to the PC via USB once the PC is booted to an OS. If it is the drive that's causing the POST failure, there's only three possible reasons: something wrong with SATA power cable/circuit, something wrong with the SATA data cable/SATA port, and/or something wrong with the hardware of the drive _(granted it could be the motherboard, but that seems unlikely with the details provided)_

Comment: Yeah, the drive does not show up in another computer. I guess this is dead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with this type if issues is that it is hard to diagnose, specially when not having the failed drive in front of you.

So we're best-guessing here.

As a first step swap every component you can swap to determine if the issue is the SSD itself or some of the other components involved, so as suggested try different PC, different adapter, different cables etc..

"computer would not start with the drive attached. ... replacing the power cable between the PSU and the drive - computer starts to BIOS, but the drive is invisible in BIOS"  - suggests a power related issue, yes.

Perhaps faulty cable did damage the drive. Could be TVS diode (if installed on your SSD) or other protective component. This is a common issue. And if this is the issue, it's often possible trouble shoot issue, determine the issue and some times solve the issue. In some cases the protective component can be simply removed (like TVS diode) so data can be recovered, in others you may need to replace it by one from a donor.

So best advice at this point would be to take the drive to someone that can diagnose and solve this type of issue.

A more general observation: data recovery success rate from SSDs is low compared to spinning drives. Often we should consider ourselves lucky if we can indeed a malfunctioning component we can remove and/or replace. Firmware issues in general are much harder to solve compared to spinning drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I might try Samsung warranty. I did not do anything unusual with the drive, it just stops showing up in BIOS.